# What is available for vintage game download on Wii?

Tags: nintendo-wii

After purchasing some Nintendo credits, what can be bought online?  MarioKart DS and GCN?  Yoshi's island DS?  Can you buy tracks for Mario Kart Wii too?  Thanks

Comment: Have you browsed through the Wii Shop Channel?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is the [list of available games in North America](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Virtual_Console_games_(North_America)).  If you are in a different region, different games are available.  There are no DS games and no GameCube games available for download.  Also, there are no extra tracks available for Mario Kart Wii.  However, there are a large number of [WiiWare games](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_WiiWare_games_(North_America)), which are similar to the Xbox Live and PSN downloadable titles - small games by independent and regular developers.

Comment: GBA and GB(C) games looks like they might appear on virtual console soon, for download on the 3DS.